Terminology for a "semi-bipartite" graph strucure (graph theory)
Let $G$ be a finite graph whose vertices can be divided into two disjoint sets $U$ and $V$ such that a vertex in $V$ can be connected to any vertex in $G$, but a vertex in $U$ can be connected only to a vertex in $V$. The graph is not a split graph because $V$ is not a clique. Is there a common terminology for such a graph in graph theory? (A semi-bipartite graph?)

This is not, technically, a class of graphs, because any graph has this form: pick any vertex $u \in V(G)$, let $U = \{u\}$, and let $V = V(G) - \{u\}$.
The triple $(G,U,V)$, however, is a well-defined structure. Even though it's not meaningful to ask whether a graph $G$ has this property, we can ask whether a triple $(G,U,V)$, where $U$ and $V$ partition $V(G)$, has the property that $U$ is an independent set.
These structures are indeed sometimes called semi-bipartite graphs. (See, for example, this paper.)
We can also observe that $V$ is not really necessary here. We can just talk about pairs $(G,U)$ where $U$ is an independent set of $G$. I would call these "graphs with a distinguished independent set $U$". This is standard terminology, not limited to graph theory, for the broader situation of having an object with a specific sub-object highlighted inside it somehow. (For example, a rooted tree is a tree with a distinguished vertex called the root; a pointed space is a topological space with a distinguished point called the basepoint.)
Graphs with a distinguished independent set have also been called Hoffman graphs in some contexts (e.g. in this paper) - not to be confused with the Hoffman graph, which is something else.
